# Равенство 4 текстовых значений

Tags: javascript

Почему 1 == 1 == 1 == 1 выдает результат true, а
'knx' == 'knx' == 'knx' == 'knx' выдает результат false

Answer (score 2, accepted):

потому что 1 это ещё и true.
попробуйте так 2 == 2 == 2 == 2 - будет false

работает примерно так:

(1 == 1) == 1 == 1 итого (true) == 1 == 1 далее ((true) == 1 ) == 1 - тоже true (так как 1 это true). Ну и так далее...

'knx' == 'knx' == 'knx' == 'knx' :
'knx' == 'knx' == 'knx' == 'knx' -> (true) == 'knx' == 'knx' -> (true == 'knx') - false

Comment: а как тогда приравнять все 4 текстовых значение?

Comment: если вы уверены что будет 4 можно через end
'string1' == 'string2' && 'string1' == 'string2' && 'string1' == 'string3' && 'string1' == 'string4'

Comment: 'string1' == 'string2' - одно лишнее )

Comment: if( 'string1' == 'string2' && 'string1' == 'string3' && 'string1' == 'string4') {
    console.log( "ура" )
} else {
    console.log( "о нет" )
}

Comment: аааа все наконец дошло спасибо

Comment: Вот через цикл можете https://codepen.io/anon/pen/JpEpjw

Answer (score 2):

Потому что это логично. 1 - истина (true), 0 - ложь (false). Результат первой операции сравнения будет логическим типом и равняется true, далее true ты сравниваешь с 'knx'. А теперь подумай над этим - `'knx' == true`.

Answer (score 0):

Потому что сравнение выполняется слева направо:

- `((1 == 1) == 1) == 1`
- `(true == 1) == 1`
- `true == 1`
- `true`

Правильно сравнивать одним из следующих способов:

```js
var a = 2, b = 2, c = 2, d = 2;
console.log(a == b && a == c && a == d);
console.log(a === b && a === c && a === d);
```